# loop twice the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want for each repeated **quai**, **veh** and **arrival_time** values I want to keep the fields with the minimum deference between
depart_time and arrival_time

[image: table]

i.e. remove both lines underline

[image]

do you think for an sql query to do that ?

Comment: *"do you think for an sql query to do that ?"* huh? That sentence, I'm afraid, doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `row_number()` function to find, partitioned by your first two columns and ordered by the millisecond time difference, the first row in each partition

```
select quai, veh, arrival_time, depart_time
from
(
  select 
    *,  
    row_number() over (partition by quai, veh order by datediff(ms, depart_time, arrival_time)) as row
  from data -- data is your table name!
) d 
where row = 1
```

Live example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6bec69a097a720761de929b92f249ccd

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to a subquery of itself:

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    MyTable t1
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            Quai,Veh,MIN(DATEDIFF(ss,Depart_Time,Arrival_Time)) d
        FROM
            MyTable
        GROUP BY Quai,Veh
    ) t2
        ON t1.Quai=t2.Quai
        AND t1.Veh=t2.Veh
        AND DATEDIFF(ss,t1.Depart_Time,t1.Arrival_Time)<>t2.d
```